# PHP URL RE-WRITE

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have a URL `http://www.domain.com/products.php?cat=women-clothing-tops` and want to re-write it to `http://www.domain.com/women-clothing-tops`, how do I go about this? Is it just a URL re-write or there are other things I need to do to get it re-written?

Comment: Did you already try some things? I could copy and paste [this page (URL Rewriting for Beginners)](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/) but maybe it's best for you to just go there.

Comment: I've been there but didn't get at what I needed. It's the reason why I'm here to seek further help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)$ /products.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Does I still get the value of "cat" in the URL "http://www.domain.com/products.php?cat=women-clothing-tops"? Please, how exactly do I use my GET method so I can get the correct page?

Comment: @OmniPotens If you go to `http://www.domain.com/women-clothing-tops`, you will get served the page `http://www.domain.com/products.php?cat=women-clothing-tops`, that's what a rewrite is

Comment: Thanks. I'll implement. I just wanted to be sure I was doing the correct thing so I don't break my codes and fall into deep confused state.

Answer (score 0):

if apache server

.htaccess

update

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . products.php
```

Comment: Thanks for your guide though I used @Jon Lin's solution above as it was more in dept to solving my challenge.